# KeyGenSpec.Builder.setUserAuthenticationRequired but not enforced

Tags: encryption, android-keystore, android-biometric-prompt

I am trying to encrypt something with a key generated in the TEE environment.

The key has the following properties:

[image]

I set the mUserAuthenticationRequired to true.

However, when I do:

```
        cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, secretKey)
        return cipher.doFinal(secretToBeEncrypted)
```

It works just fine and does not throw any exceptions for not displaying the authentication dialog.
Why is that ?